# Adding a rewrite rule to wordpress using regex

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrute rule for wordpress:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]','top' ); // check for not page in matches[1]
```

I want to add two more conditions in `$matches[1]` i.e. `(.*)` should not contain any `/` and also should not contain the string `page`.

To sum up, I want to match only strings like:

```
/abc/232
```

But not these:

```
/abc/sdsd/232
/page/232
```

Comment: Could the following pattern work `(?!page)([^/]+)/\d+/?$` where first you check that the url does not contain the word page (this might need to be tighten), if not it matches anything except `/` followed by `/` and a number

Comment: thanks it really worked for me.. just small more query.. If I want to add one more string.. like it should not contain `page` and also should not contain `age` . then how it should be written ?

Comment: Just add another -ve look-ahead `?!` so your query would be `(?!page)(?!age)([^/]+)/\d+/?$`